Symfony EasyAdmin enable Dark Mode by default
Is there any option to enable Dark Mode by default in EasyAdmin 4?
The only option I see in configureDashboard is ->disableDarkMode()

Did you check https://easycorp.github.io/blog/posts/new-in-easyadmin-4-dark-mode ?

disableDarkMode takes a boolean parameter
public function disableDarkMode(bool $disableDarkMode = true): self
{
    $this->dto->setEnableDarkMode(!$disableDarkMode);

https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/9ec576c1303176b7e51fc718f2796d8872b335ad/src/Config/Dashboard.php#L94
It defaults to true, so ->disableDarkMode() without a parameter will disable it.
Try
->disableDarkMode(false)

What I want is to only have dark mode without light.
